# Why can i not get this database to work?

Tags: mysqli, mysqlimport

Good day I am having problems getting this database to work using email instead of a username however it does not seem to work. a solution with an explanation would be highly appreciated. Thank you in advance

```
$tbl_users = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (
    id INT (11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    firstname VARCHAR (16) NOT NULL,
    lastname VARCHAR (16) NOT NULL,
    username VARCHAR (16) NOT NULL,
    age VARCHAR (16) NOT NULL,
    gender ENUM ('m','f') NOT NULL,
    email VARCHAR (255) NOT NULL,
    website VARCHAR (255) NULL,
    country VARCHAR (255) NULL,
    userlevel ENUM ('a','b','c','d') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'a',
    avatar VARCHAR (255) NULL,
    ip VARCHAR (255) NOT NULL,
    signup DATETIME NOT NULL,
    lastlogin DATETIME NOT NULL,
    notescheck DATETIME NOT NULL,
    activated ENUM ('0','1') NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    UNIQUE KEY email
    )"; 
$query = mysqli_query ($db_conx, $tbl_users);
if ($query === TRUE) {
    echo "<h3>user table created</h3>";
}   else {
    echo "<h3>user table not created</h3>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need `UNIQUE KEY (email)` with `()`- see documentation [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190024.aspx)   and [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/partitioning-limitations-partitioning-keys-unique-keys.html)